# mpg2 license on RPi3

Tags: pi-3, licensing

Do you need to purchase a mpg2 license for the RPi3?

I thought I heard somewhere that it was included in they unit purchase price.

Answer (score 3):

The base price of any Raspberry Pi contains the fee for **H.264** encoding and decoding.<sup>[1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-video-features/)</sup>
MPEG-2 is a **different** codec , whose license fee is not included in the base price.

Note that the Pi 3 might be fast enough for software decoding MPEG-2 at no cost.
This is legal in France and other European countries.

Sources : [Official Blog Announcment](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-video-features/)

Comment: Thank for clearing that up. Unfortunately, from my experience with libreelec, I don't think it's fast enough.